# Команды /comand в любом регистре

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Как сделать так, чтобы команды типа

`/start` ,

```
/help ($bot->command('start', function ($message) use ($bot) {.....)
```

можно было водить в любом регистре......

Comment: `strtolower()` ?

Comment: Так не работает в uppercase

Comment: if (strtolower($message.text) == "start") ..?

Comment: @rOtK9 А как это использовать в $bot->command('start', function ($message) use ($bot) {....

Comment: @user283655 `$command = strtolower('START');

$bot->command($command, function ($message) use ($bot) {...});`Где вместо строки 'START' подставить принимаемые комманды ?

Comment: @Эдуард Нет, не работает. Надо как-то отловить вводимую команду, а ее уже strtolower() и сравнивать с start и т п

Comment: Какой Telegram Bot API используете?

Comment: Вот: https://github.com/TelegramBot/Api